# sequences: Prove or disprove

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need your help with proving/ disproving the following:
Let $ \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ be an absolutely convergent series, and let $ \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty b_n $ be a divergent non-negative series. Then the series:
$$ \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n^2}{b_1 +b_2 + ... + b_n} $$ is convergent.

I tried playing with the harmonic sequence for $b_n$ and with $ a_n =\frac{1}{n^2}$ but that wasn't too helpful.. If you could give me intuition that would be great.
Thank you

Comment: Since $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent, boundedness of $(c_n)$ implies that $\sum (a_n c_n)$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: How about the ratio test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Since $a_n \to 0$, so $a_n^2 \le |a_n| $ when $n\to \infty$.$$ \frac{a_n^2}{b1 +b2 + ... + bn} \le \frac{a_n^2}{b1}  \le \frac{|a_n|}{b1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $i>0$ such that $b_i>0$.

$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=0$ then for large enough $n $
$$|a_n|<1$$ and

$$0\le \frac {a_n^2}{\sum_{j=1}^n b_j}\le \frac {|a_n|}{b_i} $$

use comparison.

Comment: You nearly repeat my answer.

Comment: Nothing is mine and nothing is yours. everything is OUR.